# Sibling button shrink and grow

Tags: html, css

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 130px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  right: 10px;
  position: fixed;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 96%;
}

.navbar {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" style="background-color:#6d7fcc;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
     <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
       <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
       <span>Table Of Contents</span>
     </button>
     <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
  </div>
</nav>
```

Could someone help me please. How can I shrink the button with transition (right to left) until it disappear whenever input is on focus. And grow with transition (left to right) when focus is not on input. Thank you.

Comment: `And btw, how can I remove the suggestions of previous values on this input.` Have a look at the `autocomplete` property on an input, if you search for it there's lots of info out there

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'll remove that additional question. :)

Comment: If you want your 'Table Of Contents' button to respond to the user focusing the search bar (which is how I understand your question), then you need Javascript. For example you could '.addEventListener()' to your searchbar and have the callback function trigger an animation for the button.

Comment: Hi @Jensei, I've tried this `$('input[name="search"]').on('click', function(){ $('#sidebarCollapse').css('width',0); });` and css `#sidebarCollapse{ -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out; transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out; }` like this but still has no luck. I'm just new to html, css and jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Bootstrap 4 So you can rely on flexbox properties in order to adjust the html structure to be able to keep the same visual and control the button when the input onfocus. You don't need to make the input `position:fixed` since the container is already fixed

Here is an example:

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 130px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=text]:focus+.btn {
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-width:0;
}

.navbar {
  background-color:#6d7fcc;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar .btn {
  min-width: 0;
  width: 180px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid flex-nowrap">
    <input type="text" name="search" class="order-1" placeholder="Search...">
    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info text-nowrap overflow-hidden">
       <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
       <span>Table Of Contents</span>
     </button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you look closely, the button is not fully hidden. I hit the same wall and then added the wrapper element which took the stress out of hiding the button.

Comment: Wow, great. I don't have knowledge about the '+' yet. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Because it's not a large area we need to transition, I'm recommending adding a `transition` on the `max-width` property. To keep things pure `CSS`, I flipped the position of the button and the search input. The reason I did this is so I can trigger the `transition` based on the `:focus` of the text input. Lastly, I added a container around the `button` and transition the `max-width` on that element, with its `overflow` set to hidden.

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 130px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  right: 10px;
  position: fixed;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 96%;
}

.navbar {
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.btn-container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: max-width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  max-width: 100%;
}

input[type=text]:focus + .btn-container {
  max-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" style="background-color:#6d7fcc;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
    <div class="btn-container">
      <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
         <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
         <span>Table Of Contents</span>
       </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ewvpLgt/4/)

Comment: Big thanks for this. I'll research more about that '+' on css.

Comment: @Muyie Sure thing. In `CSS`, the `+` targets the adjacent sibling. Since we can't target things that came *before*, I flipped the elements so I could leverage the `+`.